# What community are "How do you tell if..." questions in?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know if there is a certain community for questions such as, "How do you tell if a person likes you", or "How do you tell if your friends are good for you"? Are these types of questions in a certain community, are they in a different community based on the type of question, or is there no stack exchange community for it at all?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the question has a single answer, you can ask those kinds of questions anywhere they're on-topic.  E.G.:

- How do I tell if a drill bit is the right size of a wall plug goes to https://diy.stackexchange.com
- How do I know whether I have the latest kernel for my Linux distro goes to https://linux.stackexchange.com

None of your example questions go anywhere on the Stack Exchange sites though as they're **too broad** to be answered in one answer or **opinion-based**.  You'd be better off looking for a forum outside the SE network that allows endless discussions to go on for years.

Here on SE however, we actually like one question to have only one single answer. (though sometimes there are multiple answers as there are sometimes multiple ways to accomplish the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing "how do you tell if" doesn't qualify or disqualify questions from any particular site. However, it can be a sign of a very general question. That is, you're not asking "is my friend X good for me?" and later "is my friend Y good for me?" but instead are asking for a general rule to tell for any and all friends.

The specific matter of friendships, people liking you, and so on, could be a fit for [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/). However, please take the time to read a number of questions, and especially to look at any that are [on hold] so that you can see what kinds of questions don't work there.

I think you might do ok with "my friend x did a, b, and c, which I don't like, but I think I still want to be friends. How can I [whatever your goal is]?". But as I said earlier, reading other questions that get good answers is the best way to figure out how to ask. You will probably need to narrow your questions down to smaller parts that you can put together yourself into a bigger wisdom.